# Alignment of multiple variables in a linear system

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I am trying to lay out a few linear equations, but with the different variables aligned in columns like this:

```
x + y       = 1  }   x = 0
    y + 2z  = 1  }   y = 1
x     +  z  = 0  }   z = 0
```

(with a single big left } )

I have tried everything, but cannot accomplish this elegantly (without tables). Any ideas what I might try?

Here is a picture of what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not sure this is the best way to display such a thing.

Comment: @egreg Let me tell you that my Precalculus textbook displays equation systems like this (albeit with much less spacing)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is an intelligent solution with `systeme` package. Just type each term blindly, the package will arrange them automatically. For example, if you type `3z+y=10` in the first row, the term will be aligned  as shown in the output image.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{systeme,mathtools}
\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% don't use this line in your production.
\[
\sysdelim.\}\systeme{
3z +y = 10,
x + y +  z = 6,
  3y - z = 13}
\quad
\!\begin{aligned}
x   &=  a\\
y   &=  b\\
z &=  c
\end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add a link to more info about `systeme`? It's not google-friendly.

Comment: @Kundor look http://ctan.org/pkg/systeme

Comment: How do you make this work without the big brace on the right? The documentation is in French.

Comment: @Jeff : from the doc in French, replacing `\sysdelim.\}` by `\sysdelim..` above should remove the the curly brace. To give an idea of the syntax, if you wanted square braces on both sides, you would need to type `\sysdelim[]`

Answer (score 14):

Here is one suggestion using environments from `amsmath`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \left.
    \begin{alignedat}{4}
      x & {}+{} & y &       &    & = 1 \\
        &       & y & {}+{} & 2z & = 1 \\
      x &       &   & {}+{} & z  & = 0
    \end{alignedat}
  \right\} \qquad
    \begin{aligned}
     x &= 0\\
     y &= 1\\
     z &= 0
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

You might consider adding `\` or `\quad` before `\right\}` to get more space before the brace.

Comment: you don't actually need the `{}` before an equal sign when it comes right after an `&` in any alignment (as in the first three lines) since it's always a binary relation.  you *do* need them to indicate that a plus or minus isn't unary.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Perfectly correct - they were left over from testing something else - I have removed them from the code.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect! I am quite new to latex, would you mind explaining what the {} around the + is for?

Comment: @aguywithsocks they ensure the spacing aroung the `+` is ok. In this case `{}` are seen as so called *empty* atoms. To see the difference compare $+b$ to $a+b$, the spacings around `+` are different

Comment: I'm trying this solution (slightly modified) and getting the error "Package amsmath Error: Erroneous nesting of equation structures". Can you tell what might cause that?

Comment: @Jeff Sounds like you might have written `align` instead of `aligned`.  If that is not the problem, ask a new question, posting your code.

Answer (score 4):

Just in case the [`amsmath`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/amsmath) isn't available to you, you can also use a couple of `array` environments for this type of thing

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  \left.
    \begin{array}{r@{}r@{}r@{}r@{}r@{}r@{}}
      x & {}+{} & y &       &    & {}= 1 \\
        &       & y & {}+{} & 2z & {}= 1 \\
      x &       &   & {}+{} & z  & {}= 0
    \end{array}
  \right\} \qquad
    \begin{array}{r@{}l}
     x &{}= 0\\
     y &{}= 1\\
     z &{}= 0
    \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems to me a bit weird if `arara` is available but `amsmath` is not available to you.

Comment: @Marienplatz lol, yes indeed :) but that's one of the beauties of `arara`- it won't interfere if it isn't available