# Alignment at the plus signs in a system of linear equations

Tags: math-mode, equations

The following code typesets a system of linear equations in three variables. Why is there extra space before the second plus sign?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools,array}


\begin{document}



\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{} r@{}l r@{}l @{}l}
a_{1,1}x_{1,1}  &   {}+{}   a_{1,2}x_{1,2} &   {}+{}   &   a_{1,3}x_{1,3}   &   {}={}   c_{1} \\
a_{2,1}x_{2,1}  &   {}+{}   a_{2,2}x_{2,2} &   {}+{}   &   a_{3,1}x_{2,3}   &   {}={}   c_{2} \\
a_{3,1}x_{3,1}  &   {}+{}   a_{3,2}x_{3,2} &   {}+{}   &   a_{3,3}x_{3,3}   &   {}={}   c_{3}
\end{array}
\right.
.
\end{equation*}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have this space because there is something strange with alignment.

This code gives a good output. Notice also how I put fullstop after the last equation.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{mathtools,array}


\begin{document}



    \begin{equation*}
    \left\{
    \begin{array}{@{} l@{} l@{} l@{} l@{} l@{}}
    a_{1,1}x_{1,1}  &   {}+{}   a_{1,2}x_{1,2} &   {}+{}   &   a_{1,3}x_{1,3}   &   {}={}   c_{1}, \\
    a_{2,1}x_{2,1}  &   {}+{}   a_{2,2}x_{2,2} &   {}+{}   &   a_{3,1}x_{2,3}   &   {}={}   c_{2}, \\
    a_{3,1}x_{3,1}  &   {}+{}   a_{3,2}x_{3,2} &   {}+{}   &   a_{3,3}x_{3,3}   &   {}={}   c_{3}.
    \end{array}
    \right.
    \end{equation*}


\end{document}
```

While I personally prefer using `alignedat` environment:

```
\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{alignedat}{4}
&   a_{1,1}x_{1,1}  &&  +a_{1,2}x_{1,2} &&  +a_{1,3}x_{1,3} &&  =c_{1}, \\
&   a_{2,1}x_{2,1}  &&  +a_{2,2}x_{2,2} &&  +a_{3,1}x_{2,3} &&  =c_{2}, \\
&   a_{3,1}x_{3,1}  &&  +a_{3,2}x_{3,2} &&  +a_{3,3}x_{3,3} &&  =c_{3}.
\end{alignedat}
\right.
\end{equation*}
```

For more ways of typestting systems, look here: [Alignment of multiple variables in a linear system](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144610/alignment-of-multiple-variables-in-a-linear-system?rq=1)

Comment: This is the display that I wanted.

Comment: Why is `a_{1,2}` pushed against the first plus sign without the use of `l` in the alignment options?  I had `r@{}l`.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire sorry, I do not understand your question

Comment: Why is the spacing the same before and after each plus sign in your first code?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire because `{}+{}` tells LaTeX that my  plus is a binary operation, not a unitary plus, so the equal alignment is made. Remove `{}` around plus and see what happens.

Comment: Why is your last alignment coded with `r@{}`?  Why not left align `c_{1}` with the equals sign using `l@{}`?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire yes, I have understood. I have edited the question. My code worked because all the entries had the same width, thank you for correction.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility using `array` is to make the "space" between the columns be the binary/relational operators you want. To wit,

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\begin{array}{@{} l @{{}+{}} l @{{}+{}} l @{{}={}} l @{}}
a_{1,1}x_{1,1}  &  a_{1,2}x_{1,2}  &  a_{1,3}x_{1,3}  &  c_{1}, \\
a_{2,1}x_{2,1}  &  a_{2,2}x_{2,2}  &  a_{3,1}x_{2,3}  &  c_{2}, \\
a_{3,1}x_{3,1}  &  a_{3,2}x_{3,2}  &  a_{3,3}x_{3,3}  &  c_{3}.
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This has the advantage of not needing a bunch of columns. It has the downside that the source code is less clear.

Comment: Yes, this gives display that I want. Having a cumbersome code is acceptable.

Comment: How is `a_{1,1}x_{1,1}` properly aligned using `l@{{}+{}}`?  (I understand that `{{}+{}}` gives the proper spacing before and after the plus sign.)

Comment: The `l` means a left-aligned column (maybe you want `r` instead). The `@{...}` means replace the intercolumn space with the `...`. In this case, the `...` is `{}+{}`. In any event, egreg's answer with `autoaligne` looks like the simplest to me.

Comment: I replaced the first `l` with `r` and it gives me the same display.

Comment: That's because each cell in a column has the same width. Change, say, `a_{2,2}x_{2,2}` to `x_{2,2}`.

Answer (score 2):

You have the usual intercolumn space between columns 2 and 3, because you forgot `@{}` between them.

Actually, you need no array here, because all rows will have the same width nonetheless.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
a_{1,1}x_{1,1} + a_{1,2}x_{1,2} + a_{1,3}x_{1,3} = c_{1} \\
a_{2,1}x_{2,1} + a_{2,2}x_{2,2} + a_{3,1}x_{2,3} = c_{2} \\
a_{3,1}x_{3,1} + a_{3,2}x_{3,2} + a_{3,3}x_{3,3} = c_{3}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I would not put a full stop after the `cases`, because it would hang from nowhere.

For generic linear systems, you can use `autoaligne`:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{autoaligne}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\left\{
\aavcoeff{1.5}
\autoaligne{
  23x_1  + 3x_2  + x_3     = 8 \\
  8x_1   - 44x_2 + 12x_3   = \-2 \\
  \-2x_1 + x_2   + x_{3,3} = 42
}
\right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is some more generic alignments without having to use `@{}` as the inter-column space (just `\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,array}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \left\{
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \begin{array}{ r>{{}}l >{{}}l >{{}}l }
    a_{1,1} x_{1,1} & + a_{1,2} x_{1,2} & + a_{1,3} x_{1,3} & = c_1 \\
    a_{2,1} x_{2,1} & + a_{2,2} x_{2,2} & + a_{3,1} x_{2,3} & = c_2 \\
    a_{3,1} x_{3,1} & + a_{3,2} x_{3,2} & + a_{3,3} x_{3,3} & = c_3
  \end{array}
  \right.
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \left\{
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \begin{array}{ r>{{}}l >{{}}l >{{}}l }
          a x_{1,1} & + a_{1,2} x_{1,2} & + a_{1,3} x_{1,3} & = c_1 \\
    a_{2,1} x_{2,1} & + b x_{2,2}       & + a_{3,1} x_{2,3} & = c_2 \\
    a_{3,1} x_{3,1} & + a_{3,2} x_{3,2} & + c x_{3,3}       & = c_3
  \end{array}
  \right.
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
  \left\{
  \setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}
  \begin{array}{ r >{{}}c<{{}} r >{{}}c<{{}} r >{{}}l }
          a x_{1,1} & + & a_{1,2} x_{1,2} & + & a_{1,3} x_{1,3} & = c_1 \\
    a_{2,1} x_{2,1} & + &       b x_{2,2} & + & a_{3,1} x_{2,3} & = c_2 \\
    a_{3,1} x_{3,1} & + & a_{3,2} x_{3,2} & + &       c x_{3,3} & = c_3
  \end{array}
  \right.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I did not know that an `array` environment would give the appropriate spacing around the plus sign. Does the `{{}}` in `r{{}}l` put an empty space before the contents of the box following a plus sign?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire: It doesn't. `>{<stuff>}l` inserts `<stuff>` before every element in the column `l`. So, `>{{}}l` will insert an empty group before every element, and by design we started with a `+` or `=`, so the spacing will be corrected to `\mathbin` or `\mathrel`.

Comment: I think what I intended by "empty space" is what you intended by "empty group."

Comment: Do you still need `\setlength{\arraycolsep}{0pt}` before the `array` environment? Should you use `@{}` as the first optional specification?  I read in a manual - a long time ago - that the `array` environment inserts a small space preceding it.

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire: Setting `\arraycolsep` to `0pt` removes *all* column spacing; it would be similar to placing `@{}` at the start, between every column and at the end of the column specification.

Answer (score 0):

It is much simpler to write a linear system with `alignat` and `empheq` (don't load `mathtools`since `empheq` does it):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[left=\empheqlbrace]{alignat*=3}
  a_{1,1}x_{1,1} & + {}& a_{1,2}x_{1,2} & +{} & a_{1,3}x_{1,3} & = c_{1} \\
  a_{2,1}x_{2,1} & + {}& a_{2,2}x_{2,2} & +{} & a_{3,1}x_{2,3} & = c_{2} \\
  a_{3,1}x_{3,1} & + {}& a_{3,2}x_{3,2} & +{} & a_{3,3}x_{3,3} & = c_{3}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]